# Is there a function to check for data in a datafile

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

We have a school project using turbo C++. So please don't hate

Simple doubt:
How to check if there is any data stored in a datafile(of extension .dat) is there a function I can use and how?

And also how to clear a datafile of all data in it.

Comment: One way is to go to end of file (zero offset of end) and check how far that is in the file.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellg

Comment: Before working on this project start a petition and have every student sign it that says you don't want to use Turbo C++.

Comment: As for clearing a file, open for write, without ios::app

Comment: @Jeffrey doesn't work, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: A data file contains data if the data file is not empty.  Removing (deleting) the file will clear all the data inside it (so will formatting your hard drive).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux with GCC compiler, it can be done as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t getFileSize(const std::string &filename) {
    struct stat s;

    if(stat(filename.c_str(), &s) != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return s.st_size;   
}

void clearFile(const std::string &filename)
{
    truncate(filename.c_str(), 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "File size: " << getFileSize("../test.dat") << std::endl;

    clearFile("../test.dat");

    std::cout << "File size: " << getFileSize("../test.dat") << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most primitive: You could try opening the file for read and try to read some bytes.

If you can't open the file then it does not exist.

If you get no bytes then the file is empty?

Of course the file could just be set with permissions that mean you can't open it, or you can't red it.